# Laravel 5 Project Structure (Plugin System)

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, directory-structure, laravel-5

I'm trying to develop my first Laravel (5) application that can be extended by plugins. I've been reading a lot about plugin architectures, but what I'm struggling with is the *best* or preferred way to organise such a project in Laravel. I'd be very grateful for any help and advice here as I don't want to set off on the incorrect path.

Here's how I'm thinking about structuring and implementing this:

```
/ Plugins
    - PluginManager.php

    / Contracts
        - PluginInterface.php

    / Plugins

        / ExamplePlugin1
            - ExamplePlugin1.php

        / ExamplePlugin2
            - ExamplePlugin2.php
```

***Question 1:*** *Where would be the best place for the root /Plugins directory to be located? Directly in the app/ root folder or somewhere like app/Http?*

On app startup, I want the PluginManager class to scan the Plugins/Plugins/ sub directory as that's where all installed plugins will reside. At that point, the PluginManager will create a reflection instance of those plugin classes and store them in an array so that it can loop through them later and call methods on them if they exist.

***Question 2:*** As I want the PluginMananger to be available for all requests, should I be using a Service Provider and Facade for this?

***Question 3:*** Is this method efficient or could anyone offer an alternative solution?

All those plugins will implement the PluginInterface interface so that the PluginManager class can call, for example, an init() function on all plugins.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Why cant your plugins just be composer packages - and use the package system?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Thanks for your reply. The project will be installed on a number of end user's servers and I would like to make the plugin system as easy to use as possible. For this reason, I wanted to make installing the plugins as easy as dragging and dropping them into the _Plugins/Plugins_ directory and have the PluginManager class automatically detect/load them. Is there a way I can make it this easy whilst still using composer packages?

Comment: i agree with @TheShiftExchange. Packages are the standard way of extending laravel's functionality. And users should be capable of using them since almost every laravel dev uses packages sooner or later. Introducing a new qay would force them to "learn" another way of extending the funktionality..

Comment: @nozzleman Thanks for your input. Whilst I agree about the usefulness of packages, we're not talking about devs here, but _end users_ who _only consume_ the app. Their only request is ease of use. Sometimes (most times) end users want a familiar drag and drop scenario. Take Wordpress as an example, where a plugin .zip file or directory can be dropped into a plugins folder, or uploaded through a web form. Asking them to learn or even poke around in Composer or the CLI is too much in this scenario. That said, is there a way I can utilitise Composer packages but retain this ease of use?

Comment: I know october CMS has a build-in modular system and a plugin architecture. All build on L5. Check it out: https://github.com/octobercms/october

Comment: @dpstudio , please let me know if you got the solution for this issue

Comment: @dpstudio any luck with it?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

The simplest way to do this, is to create a directory "app/Plugins" ( "app/**Http**/Plugins" only if your plugins are specific to Laravel core application or routing [@RTM](http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-app-directory): *"Think of the Console and Http directories as providing an API into the "core" of your application."* ).

**Question 2**

YES!
@see: [performance issue using deferred providers](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#deferred-providers)

**Question 3**

May be can you make a kind of plugins.lock in your application root to avoid scanning "app/Plugins" on every requests ?